# Logout in Tornado doesn't work

Tags: python, logging, cookies, tornado

I wrote the login and logout handlers in Tornado, using for the login the Google external service.

The handlers are the following:

```
###############################################################################
# Manage login requests using Google authentication
###############################################################################
class AuthLoginHandler(BaseHandler, tornado.auth.GoogleMixin):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):
        if self.get_argument("openid.mode", None):
            self.get_authenticated_user(self.async_callback(self._on_auth))
            return
        self.authenticate_redirect()

    # Authentication-OK callback.
    # Save user info on the first connection.
    # Only save a last-login timestamp otherwise.
    def _on_auth(self, user):
        if not user:
            raise tornado.web.HTTPError(500, "Google auth failed")

        str_time = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()

        usr = self.db.get("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=%s", user["email"])
        if not usr:
            # Create user entry in the WSN-database
            self.lock_tables("write", ['users'])
            usr_id = self.db.execute("INSERT INTO users (email, name, last_access) \
                                                  VALUES (%s,%s,%s)",
                                                  user["email"], user["name"], str_time)
            self.unlock_tables()
        else: 
            self.lock_tables("write", ['users'])
            usr_id = usr["id"]
            self.db.execute("UPDATE users SET last_access=%s WHERE id=%s",
                            str_time, usr_id)
            self.unlock_tables()

        self.set_secure_cookie("user", str(usr_id))
    self.info("Hello <b>" + user["name"] + "</b>!")
        self.redirect(self.get_argument("next", "/"))

    # Do not log Login info
    def _log(self):
        pass

################################################################################
# Logout handler. Simply clear the "user" cookie and redirect to homepage.
################################################################################
class AuthLogoutHandler(BaseHandler, tornado.auth.GoogleMixin):
    def get(self):
        self.clear_cookie("user")
    self.notice("You have successfully logged out")
        self.redirect("/")
```

I would that, when a user is logged out, clicking on the back button of the browser he was not logged in. In other words I would that the back button doesn't work... instead, if I logged out the user, if he click the back button he can navigate in the web pages like he was always logged in..

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the page you navigate to by pression the back button are in the cache of the browser. Try typing F5 to reload the page and see if the user is still logged on.

Comment: Yes the user is relogged automatically. It's a property of google account